# Writing Related Data Files for MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to populate a mongodb database with interrelated data. I'm writing the data files myself as js objects then using node and mongoose to populate the db.

My question is two parts:

1. How do I reference interrelated data in their respective js files?
2. How would I go about populating the interrelated data?

What I've tried so far:

**File_1.js**

```
[
    {
        _id: "1",
        name: "Item 1",
        relation: "a"
    },
    // ...
]
```

**File_2.js**

```
[
    {
        _id: "a",
        name: "Item A",
        relation: "1"
    },
    // ...
]
```

Where the `relation` field would reference an `_id` that I made up.

Then I loop through the data and save it to a collection with mongoose. I get a typecast error since it's not a *12-byte ObjectId* which is what mongodb would expect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Do you need the ID to be human readable? if not you can use objectID it self or UUID.

Comment: No, not at all, I just need to be able to use one id as a reference in another js file and vice-versa. How would I use objectID? And would it possibly conflict when added to mongodb, or does mongodb ensure the same _id is never used more than once?

Comment: I've just read the mongodb docs for ```ObjectID()``` and see that it's not possible to duplicate since the first part is a timestamp so that's cool.

Still unsure how I would write my files as calling ```ObjectID()``` would eventually output a string. I guess I loop through my data, calling ```ObjectId()```, store that in  variables, then loop through the newly created data with _ids assigning the output values from ```ObjectID()```?

Comment: Yes you can do that, you create all the data as variables, then just save it to mongoDB, the mongoDriver will eventually convert _id (string) to objectID while storing it.